# Нет перевода для новой ссылки "Looking for your Teams?"

Tags: дефект, локализация, stackoverflow-for-teams

Нет перевода для новой ссылки "Looking for your Teams?"

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И описания, при нажатии на нее

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что, это фича теперь и на русском появилась? Я к тому, а должно ли вообще это быть у нас

Comment: Скорее всего просто должны убрать эти ссылки. А по переводу есть [вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387064/339911) на MSE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эти элементы, скорее всего, вообще не должны были пролезать на неанглоязычные сайты сети.

Например, именно сокрытием подобных элементов "решалась" проблема в прошлый раз: [Popup "What's SO for teams?" geometry should be more flexible in case of long translation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362268/339911)

По невозможности перевода указанных строк есть вопрос на MSE: [Unable to translate "Looking for your Teams?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387064/339911)