# Криво показывается надпись "Looking for your Teams?"

Tags: дефект, дизайн, выборы, stackoverflow-for-teams

Надпись `Looking for your Teams?` при затемнении экрана остаётся светлой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кстати, **@αλεχολυτ** [писал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12497/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-looking-for-your-teams#comment54070_12497), что её должны убрать.

Comment: Раз эту кнопочку надо вообще убрать, то зачем исправлять дефекты, которые связаны с этой кнопочкой?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нет перевода для новой ссылки "Looking for your Teams?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12497/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-looking-for-your-teams)

Comment: Зарепортил уже на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388370/339911) об этом. Подобные темы, характерные для всех сайтов, следует постить именно на MSE. А не на ruSO. P.S. спасибо за голос :)

Comment: @Зонтик ну уж точно не предложенный дубликат. Там о переводе, тут о подсветке.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ если это нужно убрать, то речи оп подсветки быть не должно =)

Comment: @Зонтик убрать на ruSO, но я не уверен, что оно будет убираться на англоязычных сайтах. Ну и это всё равно пока на уровне догадок и предположений. В любом случае, если проблема одного вопроса перестаёт быть актуальной, это не повод закрывать другой как "дубликат". Можно будет позже закрыть как "Не удаётся воспроизвести", но ни в коем случае не "дубликат".